# Installing Windows 7 on an XP/Ubuntu dual boot machine

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, windows-xp, installation, multi-boot

My machine has Windows XP and Ubuntu installed. I now want to install Windows 7 by removing Windows XP. Is it possible to do this without affecting my Ubuntu installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

First, install Windows 7 on one of your NTFS partitions, then reinstall GRUB from the Ubuntu installation CD. Most likely it will auto-detect your system partitions including Windows. If not, you will need to specify them yourself.

Comment: Can we directly install on windows xp?

Comment: Yes, why not. But I recommend you to reformat xp partition, so it will clean, or else you will end up having a lot of garbage left from the old system. Remember about backups, like bookmarks and other stuff ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to read something about Grub 2.0, which Ubuntu has. Note that installing Windows 7 will remove the Grub bootloader. Read the manual:

> https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Therefore, the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little tricky - you have to note that Windows 7 will likely overwrite your MBR. If so, all you need to do is to reload your MBR with GRUB - that should do the trick. :)

Comment: I can fix master boot record by using ubuntu recovery CD. So after installation will all my Ubuntu Data will go away or it will be safe?